# Why do I have to use "sudo" when I am in the super user group?

Tags: permissions, authorization

```
[martin@A08-R32-I196-2-FZ1RLP2 anaconda3]$ groups martin
martin : martin wheel
```

I am under my own home directory:

```
[martin@A08-R32-I196-2-FZ1RLP2 anaconda3]$ pwd
/home/martin/anaconda3
```

But when I tried delete a file in my own directory, I received this error:

```
[martin@A08-R32-I196-2-FZ1RLP2 anaconda3]$ rm test2.ipynb
mv: cannot create regular file ‘/export/.trash/test2.ipynb’: Permission denied
```

Why is that?

Comment: It looks like you have an alias or overriding script for `rm`; please [edit] in the output of `type rm`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Background

The 3rd example you showed where you're attempting to `rm` the file looks to have the `rm` command overloaded with a sequence of commands, one of which, attempts to do a `mv` of the file to `/export/.trash`.

#### Permissions

> [martin@A08-R32-I196-2-FZ1RLP2 anaconda3]$ rm test2.ipynb
>   mv: cannot create regular file ‘/export/.trash/test2.ipynb’: Permission denied

Look at the permissions for `/export/.trash/`:

```
$ ls -ld /export/.trash
```

Everything should be owned by your user 'martin' so that this account can delete files and optionally `mv` them to this directory.

I suspect someone used the `sudo` command when working in this directory and, perhaps accidentally, set the permissions of the `.trash` directory so that root owns it.

#### Overloaded command

Regarding your `rm` command. You can check if it's been overloaded as an alias or a shell function with the same name using the `type` command. Examples:

```
$ type -f rm
rm is aliased to `rm -i'

$ type -f mv
mv is aliased to `mv -i'
```

Here we can see that the `mv` and `rm` commands have been overloaded as aliases to `mv -i` and `rm -i`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the output from `rm` indicates the `rm` is an alias or a function doing something else, from the path name it seems to try to move to a trash directory instead of removing.

To address the original question, group 0 (`wheel`) basically means nothing. On BSD based systems, `su` (not `sudo`) to root is restricted to members of the `wheel` grouup, but that is just a function of the `su` command on BSD and not a function of the OS itself.

The `sudo` command is commonly used on Linux. It is highly configurable. Membership in group 0 can be made a requirement to be able to use `sudo`, but doesn't automatically use `sudo`.